# Android ffmpeg how to access watermark png

Tags: android, watermark, android-ffmpeg

ffmpeg is producing error messages because it does not like the png file that I have included.  The png starts out as an icon, but I think that ffmpeg wants it to be a file.  Do I have to do this to make it available to ffmpeg?  Here's what I do:

```
 Bitmap watermark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.watermark);

FileOutputStream   fos = model.controller.openFileOutput("watermark.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         ObjectOutputStream of  = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
         boolean success = watermark.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, of);
         of.flush();
         of.close();
```

I provide the file path to ffmpeg this way:

```
String watermarkPath = model.getFilesDir() + "/watermark.png";
```

Which results in:

```
/data/user/0/com.example.example/files/watermark.png
```

I call ffmpeg with this array

```
String [] splitString = new String[]
            {
                    "-i", fileName,
                    "-i", watermarkPath,
                    "-filter_complex", "overlay=10:10",
                    newFileName};
```

And I get these error messages, all about the PNG.

```
 ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
  configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/data/user/0/com.scenebot.scenebot/files/32ec5e5e-29e6-4f9a-99ae-04d0ab9d74a1.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-05-17 04:09:21
    com.android.version: 7.0
  Duration: 00:00:02.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17103 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709/bt709/smpte170m), 1920x1080, 16846 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.67 fps, 29.67 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-17 04:09:21
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 255 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-17 04:09:21
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
[png @ 0xf44fe800] Invalid PNG signature 0xACED00057A000004.
[image2 @ 0xf44af600] decoding for stream 0 failed
[image2 @ 0xf44af600] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: png, none(pc)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
/data/user/0/com.scenebot.scenebot/files/watermark.png: could not find codec parameters
Input #1, image2, from '/data/user/0/com.scenebot.scenebot/files/watermark.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3678 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, none(pc), 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[buffer @ 0xf4350000] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size
[buffer @ 0xf4350000] Unable to parse option value "-1" as pixel format
[buffer @ 0xf4350000] Unable to parse option value "0x0" as image size
[buffer @ 0xf4350000] Error setting option video_size to value 0x0.
[graph 0 input from stream 1:0 @ 0xf44ab220] Error applying options to the filter.
Error configuring complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

I have been working on this for about four hours.  Going crazy I am.

Comment: Did you find solution for this? Seems I'm facing with similar problem and I'm beginner with `FFmpeg`

Comment: We THINK the  problem is that the standard compiled ffmpeg that comes from implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2' does not include png support.  So we have to compile it.  Not looking forward to the compile process.

Comment: Never did find a solution.  We're going to hire one of the few people who have posted solutions.